# lwip based TCP, loses communication

Tags: lwip

I am using a XMC4500 (infineon) with lwip for TCP communication.
Everything works fine when communicating with the PC, many transactions work fine, for hours and days.
The board is part of a whole system communicating(with PC) with many other MCU based boards.
We have noticed that every week or so the communication stops.
I have logs that show nothing, just that the XMC4500 board stops answering.

Is there a way to add a lwip-TCP watchdog that check communication from time to time and in case of no response it resets the lwip?
Has anybody else had some kind of thing happen?

Comment: back to this problem:

Comment: After tracking the the problem in FaultISR() I found the origin of the problem in the following set of code lines: I couldnt pin point the line with the problem.
#if LWIP_DHCP
    if((g_ui32LocalTimer - g_ui32DHCPFineTimer) >= DHCP_FINE_TIMER_MSECS){
        g_ui32DHCPFineTimer = g_ui32LocalTimer;
        dhcp_fine_tmr();}
I didnt investigate deeper but just got the exception to return after saving the data in FLASH and incrementing the error counter  - no problem after that.

Does anyone have any similar problem of this kind referring to the dhcp_fine_tmr function ?
Maccabi